# If $V \subset H$ compact, is $L^2(0,T;V) \subset L^2(0,T;H)$ compact too?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

As the question states, if we have the compact embedding of Hilbert spaces $V \subset H$, is $L^2(0,T;V) \subset  L^2(0,T;H)$ compact too?

If not true in general, is it true for $V=H^1(\Omega)$ and $H=L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: What if $V=H=\Bbb R$?

Comment: What does $L^2(0,T;V)$ mean?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Fairly common notation for the Lebesgue-Bochner space of functions valued in Banach space $V$.

Comment: @DavidMitra But $\mathbb{R}$ is not compactly embedded in itself.

Comment: Isn't the identity a compact operator (the image of a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence)?

Comment: @michael_faber In the language of operators, the embedding of $\mathbb R^n$ into itself is compact for any $n \ge 0$: The image of the unit ball is bounded and thus (because of the finite dimension) precompact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to know whether the unit ball of $L^2(0,T;V)$ is relatively compact (=has compact closure) in $L^2(0,T;H)$. A readable treatment of relative compactness in Lebesgue-Bochner  spaces is in [Tightness, integral equicontinuity and compactness for evolution problems in Banach spaces](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=ASNSP_2003_5_2_2) by Rossi,  and Savaré, see Theorem 1. In a nutshell, you need: boundedness with respect to some Banach space compactly embedded in $H$ (which you have), and integral equicontinuity (which you **don't** have). Without integral equicontinuity, a counterexample is provided by $f_n(t)=e^{int}\varphi $, where $\varphi$ is any fixed element of $V$.