# Is the embedding $L^2(0,T;H^1) \subset L^2(0,T;L^2)$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces

Is the embedding $L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)) \subset L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample, inspired by the answer to this question:

[If $V \subset H$ compact, is $L^2(0,T;V) \subset L^2(0,T;H)$ compact too?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441534/if-v-subset-h-compact-is-l20-tv-subset-l20-th-compact-too?rq=1)

Take $v\in H^1$, $T=\pi$, 
$$
\phi_n(t) = \sin(n t)v.
$$
Since $\sin(n \circ)$ converges weakly but not strongly to zero in $L^2(0,T)$, it follows that
$\phi_n$ converges weakly to zero in $L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

If there would be a subsequence of $(\phi_n)$ converging strongly to zero in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$, then this would imply $\sin(n \circ) \to 0$ in $L^2(0,T)$, which is a contradiction.

Hence, the embedding is not compact. You need some control of the time derivative (see Aubin-Lions theorem).